# Is it possible to disable File (Field) Paths for a certain field?

Tags: files, uri

As I'm having a hard time using Filefield Paths together with Filedepot (see http://drupal.org/node/1572170) I'm wondering if its somehow possible to disable Filefield Path on a per-field (or content type) basis? Filedepot works nicely when FFP is disabled and puts its file inside its directory structure, but all other file fields should be processed by FFP.

If I could somehow disable FFP processing for the field "filedepot_folder_file" everything should work fine.

Regards,
Daniel